# Meaning of this notation AR(||1,3||)

Tags: autoregressive, notation

I can't understand the meaning of this writing: AR(||1,3||). I don't know the meaning of the "||".

Edit: I've found also this notation: ARMA(1, ||1,4||). Maybe could be useful.

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: @Glen_b Enders, *Applied econometric time series*

Comment: If this is a pure AR time series the use of two orders is also puzzling. Could it be that MA terms are being included?

Comment: If you specify the full reference (including edition and page number), someone may be able to check. If we're just going to guess, mine would be an AR(3) but with the lag-2 coefficient set to zero (i.e. lags 1 and 3 only). But the notation is not standard as far as I know.

Comment: @ChrisHaug Enders, *Applied econometric time series* (4th edition). Page 115 and page 116.

Comment: @ChrisHaug I've found in the Programming manual attached to the manual (you can find it [here](http://time-series.net/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/RATS_Program_Manual03112014.69182207.pdf). Look at section 2.7) strong evidence that you are right. AR(||1,3||) means an AR(3) with the lag-2 coefficient set to zero (in the specific example of the book he do it because the AR coefficient of the lag-2 does not seems significant). As a consequence I suppose that ARMA(1,||1,4||) means that the MA coefficients of lag-3 and lag-4 are forced to be zero